# How can I draw range of delivery on Google Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know how to add the Google Map on my restaurant's webpage, but how can I have range of delivery (semi-transparent polygon)?

Here is an example: [link](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=205169863221025505100.0004b0255c8e6365a67df)

Maybe it can be done by somehow put a semi-transparent image on Google Map? But how can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polygon is the way to go, with a "event.latLng" click listener to help plot your region

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/MFfTc/2/

Clicking on the map will define the polygon vertices, then you can copy that to your real map. Remove the last comma and add a bracket ].

Comment: Thanks. This solution is extremely easy to use. Thank you. P.S. How can I change the color of this canvas?

Comment: Sorry, can you explain better what you mean by canvas?

Comment: Sorry, I meant semi-transparent polygon. In your example it is gray. Can I change this color in CSS or in other way?

Comment: Yes, there are a bunch of options I left out. The basic ones I added to an updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MFfTc/4/ and look for the new google.maps.Polygon. (strokeColor: "#006600", strokeWeight: 4, and fillColor: "#FF00DD") The API Reference shows all possible options. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolygonOptions

Answer (score 0):

You could draw a polygon with google earth and then save it to a KML file and load it on google maps api v3

```
var myOptions = {
   zoom: 4,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922),
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

kml_layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml');
kml_layer.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Google Maps API, you can create a [Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polygons) overlay. You need to know the coordinates of each vertex. If you don't, you could use the [Google Maps API Drawing Tools](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#drawing_tools) to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link that allows you to place moveable markers on Google Maps and paste html code into your site:  http://www.nirmalpatel.com/ourarea/